# Facing an issue with the logical processing order of and / or clauses in a SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm creating a `#Results` table and inserting certain values using the following script:

```
create table #Results
(
    ResOID int identity(1,1),
    FndAbbr varchar(16),
    ResVal varchar(100)
)

insert into #Results
values ('Na', '110'), ('Na', '130'), 
       ('K', '5.02'), ('K', '5.18'), ('K', '3.60'), ('K', '7.00');
```

Now, if I execute this query:

```
select * 
from #Results
where 
    --(FndAbbr = 'NA' and (convert(int, ResVal) < 120 or convert(int, ResVal) > 160))
    --or
    (FndAbbr = 'K' and (convert(float, ResVal) < 3.0 or convert(float, ResVal) > 6.0))
```

or the query:

```
select * 
from #Results
where 
    (FndAbbr = 'NA' and (convert(int, ResVal) < 120 or convert(int, ResVal) > 160))
    --or
    --(FndAbbr = 'K' and (convert(float, ResVal) < 3.0 or convert(float, ResVal) > 6.0))
```

it works fine.

However, when I uncomment both the lines and execute the query:

```
select * 
from #Results
where 
    (FndAbbr = 'NA' and (convert(int, ResVal) < 120 or convert(int, ResVal) > 160))
    or
    (FndAbbr = 'K' and (convert(float, ResVal) < 3.0 or convert(float, ResVal) > 6.0))
```

I get an error

> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '5.0' to data type int

Why is it behaving differently when the "or" becomes functional? Also, what changes need to be made in order for the query to work?

Comment: Looks like you have  data that does not cast successfully and is filtered out by the `FndAbbr` predicates. SQL Server can always evaluate expressions before filters, use try_convert instead of convert so it doesn't matter if it does this for rows that wont convert successfully

Comment: Have you tried separating the query like this ?
`select * 
    from #Results
    where (FndAbbr = 'NA' and (convert(int, ResVal) < 120 or convert(int, ResVal) > 160))
  union

select * 
from #Results
where 
    (FndAbbr = 'K' and (convert(float, ResVal) < 3.0 or convert(float, ResVal) > 6.0))`

Answer (score 1):

this error is because of `Reseal` column Type you cannot Convert Float into Int in sql server 
try this :

```
insert into #Results
values ('Na', '110'), ('Na', '130'), 
       ('K', '5'), ('K', '5'), ('K', '3'), ('K', '7');
```

it work properly.

here is another way if you dont  want change your data in Result,you can use `FLOOR` Or `CEILING` Function for cast ResVal  to int .

```
select * from #Results
    where 
    (FndAbbr = 'NA' and CEILING(CAST(ResVal as float))<120 )
    or
    (FndAbbr = 'K' and(convert(float,ResVal)<3.0 or convert(float,ResVal)>6.0))
```

Answer (score 0):

In your first query, I suspect that SQL Server is only applying `convert(int, ResVal)` against records where FndAbbr = 'NA'. Or in other words, I believe the records are first filtered to only those where FndAbbr = 'NA' before checking the second condition.

In your dataset, ResVal is a valid integer when `FndAbbr = 'NA'` but not when `FndAbbr is 'K'` ('5.02', '5.18', etc. are valid floats, but not ints)

In your third query, I suspect that the inclusion of the `FndAbbr = 'K'` records is causing `convert(int, ResVal)` to be evaluated against those records as well, causing the error.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `try_convert` as below.It returns a value cast to the specified data type if the cast succeeds; else null.

```
select * 
from #Results
where 
    (FndAbbr = 'NA' and 
    (try_convert(int, ResVal) < 120 or try_convert(int, ResVal) > 160))
    or
    (FndAbbr = 'K' and 
    (try_convert(float, ResVal) < 3.0 or try_convert(float, ResVal) > 6.0)
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server does NOT guarantee that the filtering in a `WHERE` occurs before calculations in the `SELECT`.  In fact, SQL is a *descriptive* language.  A SQL query describes the result set.  It does not specify the order of operations.

This is true for subqueries and CTEs as well.  The SQL engine is free to rearrange the operations -- if it meets the needs of the query.

The conversions can occur in different places in the query plan.  In particular, SQL Server will push the conversions to the the nodes that read the data.  This is considered an optimization -- which is good.  I do consider mishandling the error as a bug, although Microsoft clearly does not agree with me.

All supported versions of SQL Server support `TRY_CONVERT()` and `TRY_CAST()` which solves this problem:

```
where (FndAbbr = 'NA' and (try_convert(int, ResVal) < 120 or try_convert(int, ResVal) > 160)) or
      (FndAbbr = 'K' and (try_convert(float, ResVal) < 3.0 or try_convert(float, ResVal) > 6.0))
```

In older versions, you can use `case` expression to do almost the same thing.  SQL *does* guarantee the order of evaluation of clauses within a `case` expression.

BUT the better solution is to store the data using the correct type.  In this case, I would suggest some sort of numeric.